# Play Store - This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement (ABI Split x86 build)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app that is split on ABI like this by adding a block similar to this in the build.gradle file:

```
splits {
    abi {
        ...
        reset()
        include("x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64")
    }
}
```

With versioning configured in the following manner: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions

When I try to upload the 4 APKs to the play store, the APK for the x86 ABI has an error that says:

```
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [1100002]
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.
```

The breakdown of version codes is the following:

1. armeabi-v7a - 1100001
2. x86 - 1100002
3. x86_64 - 1100003
4. arm64_v8a - 1100004

Why is it saying that I need to include 64 bit binaries in the APK specifically split for 32 bit devices? The same error does not occur for the arm based APKs, only the 32 bit x86 APK. What is the point of splitting them if I need to include 64bit resources with the x86 ABI?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in our case was that we uploaded the x86_64 APK first, and then attempted to add the 3 other APKs after the fact. I think that Play Store doesn't recognize that there is already an x86_64 APK available and it only looks at the APKs that are in the current upload. We couldn't select the x86_64 APK alongside the 3 others, so I think that the tool mistakenly assumed we weren't uploading a 64 bit compatible APK.

Not 100% sure if this was the cause here - but this is the only thing I could find.

Answer (score 0):

"Use the Android App Bundle publishing format" means, you should switch from .apk to .aab format, and the bundle will have both 32bit and 64bit and google play store takes care of delivering only what is needed to the device.